# Why is the `compress` method not being called on my subclass of MultiValueField?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-models, django-multiwidget

I've implemented a custom `DurationField` in Django that stores an integer that represents a duration in number of seconds. I've also defined a custom multiwidget that takes in five different number inputs (representing the number of weeks, days, hours, minutes, and seconds).

I've managed to get it working in the admin, and `decompress` appears to be working as expected; when I alter the values in the interpreter and save them, they appear correctly in the five fields. However, `compress` doesn't seem to be getting called; when I attempt to change the values (or simply save the form without changing them), I get the `Enter a whole number.` error from `IntegerField`. It appears as though the entire list of values (e.g. `[u'0', u'1', u'2', u'0', u'0']`) is being passed to `to_python`.

I feel like I'm missing/overlooking something small, but I think I've been staring at my code for too long to figure out what it could be.

Here's my `model_fields.py`:

```
from datetime import timedelta                                                   

from django.db.models import PositiveIntegerField                                
from django.forms import IntegerField, MultiWidget                               
from django.forms.fields import MultiValueField                                  
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput  # NumberInput in Django 1.6          


DURATION_FORM_FIELDS = ('weeks', 'days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds')


class DurationMultiWidget(MultiWidget):                                          

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):                                              
        _widgets = tuple(                                                        
            [TextInput(attrs=attrs) for field in DURATION_FORM_FIELDS]           
        )                                                                        
        super(DurationMultiWidget, self).__init__(_widgets, attrs)               

    def decompress(self, value):                                                 

        if value:                                              
            td = timedelta(seconds=value)                                        
            return [                                                             
                getattr(td, label, 0) for label in DURATION_FORM_FIELDS          
            ]                                                                    
        return [None for field in DURATION_FORM_FIELDS]

class DurationMultiValueField(MultiValueField):                                  

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                                         
        fields = tuple(                                                          
            [IntegerField(label=field_label) for field_label in DURATION_FORM_FIELDS]
        )                                                                        
        super(DurationMultiValueField, self).__init__(fields=fields, *args, **kwargs)

    def compress(self, data_list):                                                                                                                                                          
        duration_dict = dict(zip(DURATION_FORM_FIELDS, data_list))               
        timedelta_object = timedelta(**duration_dict)                            
        return int(timedelta_object.total_seconds())                            


class DurationField(PositiveIntegerField):                                       

    def get_internal_type(self):                                                 
        return 'DurationField'                                                   

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):                                               
        defaults = {'form_class': DurationMultiValueField}                       
        defaults.update(kwargs)                                                  
        return super(DurationField, self).formfield(**kwargs)                   


from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules                        
add_introspection_rules([], ["^polls\.model_fields\.DurationField"])
```

Here's `admin.py`:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Poll
from .model_fields import DurationMultiWidget


class PollAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

    class Meta:                                                                  
        model = Poll                                                             
        widgets = {                                                             
            'limit': DurationMultiWidget(),                                      
        }                                                                        

    ...                                                                       


class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):                                               
    form = PollAdminForm


admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
```

And here's `models.py`, just in case:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _ 

class Poll(models.Model):                                                                                                         
    ...                                                                             
    limit = DurationField(_('limit'), default=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, it was a typo: under the `formfield()` method, I accidentally passed in `**kwargs` instead of `**defaults`.

As an aside, in the rare instance that someone is trying to do the exact same thing, you have to do a `kwargs.pop('min_value')` in the `DurationMultiValueField.__init__` (since it's a PositiveIntegerField).